# Can a standing wave on a rope be a driving oscillator for a spring-mass system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, spring, string, coupled-oscillators

Can a standing wave created on a rope be used as a driving oscillator for a spring-mass system coupled with it?

Comment: Hi Atharva, I've removed your extra question because we prefer to have one question per post. You can post your other question separately. (Though it might be too broad for this site.)

Comment: Hi Atharva, I would go along with David's suggestion, but most of my answer is with the coupled oscillator part. I did not see David's comment until I posted my answer, but I can split them up.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. How do you think this would work? Can you supply a diagram? Do you think it is possible or not, and for what reason(s)?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, a coupled oscillator is a system of masses, which are connected by spring-like connections. The motion of coupled oscillators is  important on both the micro and macro scales.

Take a $CO2$ molecule, it's  vibrational energy states can be treated as, for small displacements,  the result of coupled oscillators. Other coupled oscillators can be seen in the passing on  of energy in  the molecular arrangement of a crystalline solid.

[image]

Coupled oscillators.

I am guessing you want a real example, rather than the standard models of pendulums, and modes and all the math that goes with them.

Can I give you a real life  example of where coupled oscillators worked, in a way that nobody wanted?

The Millennium Bridge, officially known as the London Millennium Footbridge, is a pedestrian steel suspension bridge for crossing the River Thames in London, which  initially opened in June 2000.

The bridge was soon called "Wobbly Bridge" after pedestrians crossing it felt an unexpected swaying motion. The bridge was closed after two days of limited access, and remained  closed for almost two years while modifications were made to get rid of the swaying 
motion. It reopened in 2002.

[image: Millennium Bridge London]

This swaying motion was due to coupled oscillators, but biological ones, people in fact. On the day of opening, the bridge was crossed by 90,000 people, with up to 2,000 on the bridge at any one time. The movements of the bridge  were  known as synchronous lateral excitation, connected with coupled oscillations.   People walking across the bridge had a natural swaying motion, (that every walker has) and this caused coupled oscillations in the bridge, which then started to sway in time with the walking (and swaying) patterns of the people, in a feedback loop. This in turn increased the amplitude of the bridge oscillations and continually reinforced the effect of unintended coupled oscillations.

Other real life applications of  coupled oscillations are [Lasers Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser) and many components  of electrical circuits.

> Can a standing wave created on a rope be used as a driving oscillator for a spring mass system coupled with it.

I am not sure if you mean, once you establish the standing wave, do you continue to feed energy into it? Obviously you will need to,  otherwise it will undergo overdamping, without forced vibrations of the rope, it will have all the energy removed from it within a very short timescale. It does seem a very roundabout way of providing energy to aspring mass system

Answer (score 0):

If a horizontal rope is attached to a mass hanging from a vertical spring, you will need some way to prevent the tension in the rope from moving the mass in the horizontal direction.